# how to remove contexts in TPM2 version 3.1.3 to free TPM memory

Tags: tpm

I'm using tpm2-tools version 3.1.3 on Raspberry Pi CM4. It turns out it doesn't have `tpm2_flushcontext` which was added in v4.0.

Is there any other tools in tpm2-tools 3.1.3 that can remove contexts?  My goal is to free up some memory in TPM as it returned the following error:

```
$ tpm2_rc_decode 0x902
error layer
  hex: 0x0
  identifier: TSS2_TPM_RC_LAYER
  description: Error produced by the TPM
format 0 warning code
  hex: 0x02
  name: TPM2_RC_OBJECT_MEMORY
  description: out of memory for object contexts
```

Comment: I got help from tpm2 mailing list, and upgrade my OS and then to tpm2-tools 5.0. So never mind this question.

Comment: Would be good to mark this questions as answered. Bonus points if you link to the mailing thread archive.